# unable to locate package software-centre on chromebook

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec

I've just installed Ubuntu via crouton on my hp chromebook 14, but I need to install software centre as I can't do anything without it.

I try to run `apt-get install software-centre`

but it returns with the error `E: unable to locate package software-centre`

I posted my problem on ask Ubuntu, but they told me to come over here as crouton is not considered official Ubuntu.

How do I get rid of this error.

Comment: [Cross posting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592732/unable-to-locate-package-software-centre-on-chromebook) is not allowed here, so remove the post on Ask Ubuntu, or this will be closed. You were also [clearly told to include information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592732/unable-to-locate-package-software-centre-on-chromebook#comment824891_592732), not just to come here, with your question. So please update your question with that information. And read the [help tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't done so yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the American spelling:

```
apt-get install software-center
```

(this will install https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center).

Comment: wow i cannot believe it was that small of a problem! thanks for the help it is greatly appreciated